# How to fix? Except on SendRequest (wait 60 seconds and resend) - Python InstagramAPI

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram

I am trying to create an Instagram AutoAcceper CLI Based. When I run my code it works until 2 followers are accepted and a error occurs.

I have tried running it on different networks, to check if its being rate limited and tried running it on linux and windows. The problem may be how I process the login session. I also read that I may need a private key (PK) from here https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python/issues/299 but I am not sure if that correlates into my problem, and I am not sure how to incorporate that into my code

HERE IS MY ERROR:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu187.png)

The code uses https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python

https://pastebin.com/9Hyzq9Ae
 I am not sure what is causing the error so here is the full code

```
    while __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        userid = getPendingInfo(insta)
    except:
        pass
    if userid:
        for check in range(len(userid)):
            try:
                currentUserID = userid[check]
                approve(insta, currentUserID)
                number += 1
                spinner.start('\n SwiftAccept | Accepted: ' + str(number))
            except:
                pass
```

`

In actuality it should be accepting without any interruptions. Even if it was rate limited it would just not accept instead of doing the error that it is doing. Additionally rate limits happen at 1000 accepts in 10 minutes

Comment: Welcome to SO! One thing that is missing from your question that might help is the details of the error... what error are you getting? That would help others to figure out what's going on. Currently, your code is ignoring any errors with `except: pass` - try catching the error and logging it to see what's failing.

Comment: Yeah I added the error @Kryten